# View Resolved SQL Text in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to look through all databases SQL has referenced in Snowflake.

I am querying QUERY_HISTORY and using the SQL_TEXT field. In most cases, I can identify database names by parsing the SQL_TEXT.

Problem:
If objects are called using Variables and running SQL's using identifier function then the actual resolved object name/database name is not getting populated.
Ex:

```
select * from table(information_schema.query_history()) where query_text like '%$%' and execution_status='SUCCESS'
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUqnR.png)

There is one way to look at DATABASE_NAME but it will be the context database in use which might not be correct.

Is there any other way to identify all databases/objects referenced by SQL's run on Snowflake

Answer (score 1):

Post studying more seems ACCESS_HISTORY will resolve the issue